# Power Outage Has Subtly Corrupted External Hard Disk

Tags: mount, external-hdd

Added a 3rd Addendum to respond to the question/comment of Archemar.

---

Added a 2nd Addendum to give a more complete response to the question/comment of sina bala.

---

I use a USB cable and an external docking station to connect an internal 6tb hard disk.  I recently had a power outage as I was writing to the hard disk.  Subsequently, I can not mount, unmount, or re-format the hard disk.

I am unsure what I need to do to either salvage the data on the hard disk or force the removal of the partition, so that I can re-format the hard disk and start over.  I am running Linux Mint 20.3.

`lsblk` shows

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   931G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 465.3G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 465.3G  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0   2.7T  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0   2.7T  0 part /media/steve/tv_movies_3tb_04
sdd      8:48   0   5.5T  0 disk 
└─sdd1   8:49   0   5.5T  0 part /media/steve/tv_movies_6tb_02
sde      8:64   0   5.5T  0 disk 
└─sde1   8:65   0   5.5T  0 part
```

The external drive has been assigned to sde1, but will not mount or unmount.  Further, the following command hangs:

`sudo parted /dev/sde`

The drive (supposedly) "assigned" to sde1 has the label /tv_movies_6tb_03.

The command `ls -al /media/steve/tv_movies_6tb_03` yields

```
total 8
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 Mar  1 15:21 .
drwxr-x---+ 5 root root 4096 Mar  1 15:21 ..
```

So, the system (somewhat) thinks that the drive exists with no files on it.  The docking station activity light stays blinking for over 30 minutes.  So, something is wrong, but I have no idea how to recover either the data or the hard drive itself.

---

Addendum-1

For what it's worth, if no one has a better idea, my next try will be

`sudo mke2fs -t ext4 -L tv_movies_6tb_03 /dev/sde1`

My thinking is that under normal circumstances, this command seems to write (what looks like) a file allocation table to the hard disk.

---

Addendum-2

> So, is the drive currently formatted as ext4 also?

Prior to the hard disk being corrupted, I followed my standard procedure (shown below) for formatting a new hard disk from Amazon:

```
1. Use lsblk to determine the location that the drive is assigned to.
```

Number 1. showed that the drive was connected to sde.

```
2.  sudo parted /dev/sde
        mklabel gpt
        mkpart primary ext4 1MiB 100%
        quit
```

Number 2. created the partition.

```
3.  Repeat lsblk to verify that partition is now assigned to sde1.

4.  sudo mke2fs -t ext4 -L tv_movies_6tb_03 /dev/sde1

5.  mount /dev/sde1 /media/steve/tv_movies_6tb_03

6.  sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sde1
```

Number 6. was done to reclaim space on the hard drive.

```
7.  sudo chmod -R 777 /media/steve/tv_movies_6tb_03/
```

---

Addendum-3

> any lines containing sde from dmesg ? e.g. what is result from dmesg | grep sde ?

`sde` output shown below, after `lsblk` output.  For what its worth, the (external) docking station activity light is continually blinking, as if the system is having trouble "recognizing" the drive.  Can't mount the drive.

```
steve@steve-H97-D3H:~/java$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   931G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 465.3G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 465.3G  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0   2.7T  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0   2.7T  0 part /media/steve/tv_movies_3tb_04
sdd      8:48   0   5.5T  0 disk 
└─sdd1   8:49   0   5.5T  0 part /media/steve/tv_movies_6tb_02
sde      8:64   0   5.5T  0 disk 
└─sde1   8:65   0   5.5T  0 part 


steve@steve-H97-D3H:~/java$ dmesg | grep sde
[ 4904.984511] Buffer I/O error on dev sde1, logical block 212, lost async page write
[ 4904.984514] Buffer I/O error on dev sde1, logical block 213, lost async page write
[ 4904.984515] Buffer I/O error on dev sde1, logical block 214, lost async page write
[ 4904.984518] Buffer I/O error on dev sde1, logical block 615, lost async page write
[ 4904.984519] Buffer I/O error on dev sde1, logical block 616, lost async page write
[ 4904.984520] Buffer I/O error on dev sde1, logical block 617, lost async page write
[ 4904.984521] Buffer I/O error on dev sde1, logical block 618, lost async page write
[ 4904.984522] Buffer I/O error on dev sde1, logical block 619, lost async page write
[ 4904.984523] Buffer I/O error on dev sde1, logical block 620, lost async page write
[ 4904.984525] Buffer I/O error on dev sde1, logical block 621, lost async page write
[ 4904.988342] EXT4-fs (sde1): error loading journal
[ 4905.001963] EXT4-fs (sde1): unable to read superblock
[ 4905.004543] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 4905.253206] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 4929.766824] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Spinning up disk...
[ 4944.097538] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] 11721045168 512-byte logical blocks: (6.00 TB/5.46 TiB)
[ 4944.097541] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] 4096-byte physical blocks
[ 4944.097802] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
[ 4944.097804] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 4944.098360] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 4944.098847] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
[ 4944.179825] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
[ 5818.078639]  sde: sde1
[ 5908.060307] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#29 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 5 inflight: CMD 
[ 5908.060317] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#29 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 08 00 00 00 f8 00 00
[ 5908.060328] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#26 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 4 inflight: CMD 
[ 5908.060332] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#26 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 88 00 00 00 78 00 00
[ 5908.060338] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#25 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 3 inflight: CMD 
[ 5908.060342] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#25 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 48 00 00 00 30 00 00
[ 5994.077830] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#28 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 5 inflight: CMD 
[ 5994.077839] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#28 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 08 00 00 00 f8 00 00
[ 6123.337837] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 6123.580085] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 6135.095365] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Spinning up disk...
[ 6148.407985] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] 11721045168 512-byte logical blocks: (6.00 TB/5.46 TiB)
[ 6148.407990] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] 4096-byte physical blocks
[ 6148.408244] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
[ 6148.408248] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 6148.408884] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 6148.409373] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
[ 6148.500572]  sde: sde1
[ 6148.521904] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
[ 6149.290883] EXT4-fs (sde1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[ 8402.582251] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#22 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 11 inflight: CMD 
[ 8402.582260] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#22 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 04 f4 48 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[13680.390821] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#16 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[13680.390829] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#16 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 01 5d 45 58 80 00 00 00 60 00 00
[13830.153939] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#4 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[13830.153947] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#4 CDB: ATA command pass through(12)/Blank a1 08 2e d1 01 00 4f c2 00 b0 00 00
[13854.474428] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#29 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 7 inflight: CMD 
[13854.474436] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#29 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 10 69 fc 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[13854.474447] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#28 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 6 inflight: CMD 
[13854.474451] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#28 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 10 69 f8 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[13854.474457] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#19 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 5 inflight: CMD 
[13854.474460] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#19 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 10 69 f4 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[13854.474466] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#18 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 4 inflight: CMD 
[13854.474470] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#18 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 10 69 f0 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[13854.474477] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#17 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 3 inflight: CMD 
[13854.474481] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#17 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 10 69 ec 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[13854.474486] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#16 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD 
[13854.474490] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#16 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 10 69 e8 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[13854.474496] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#8 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 23 inflight: CMD 
[13854.474500] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#8 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 10 6a 18 40 00 00 04 00 00 00
[13854.474506] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#7 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 22 inflight: CMD 
[13854.474510] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#7 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 10 6a 14 40 00 00 04 00 00 00
[13854.474516] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#6 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 14 inflight: CMD 
[13854.474519] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#6 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 10 6a 10 40 00 00 04 00 00 00
[13854.474525] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#5 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 13 inflight: CMD 
[13854.474529] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#5 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 10 6a 10 00 00 00 00 40 00 00
[13854.474535] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#3 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 10 inflight: CMD 
[13854.474538] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#3 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 10 6a 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[13854.474544] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#2 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 9 inflight: CMD 
[13854.474548] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#2 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 10 6a 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[13854.474554] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#1 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 12 inflight: CMD 
[13854.474558] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#1 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 10 6a 0c 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[13854.474563] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#0 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 11 inflight: CMD 
[13854.474567] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#0 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 10 6a 08 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[15537.965377] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#18 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 11 inflight: CMD 
[15537.965385] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#18 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 14 bf f0 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[15537.965395] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#17 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 10 inflight: CMD 
[15537.965399] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#17 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 14 bf ec 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[15537.965405] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#16 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 9 inflight: CMD 
[15537.965409] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#16 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 14 bf e8 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[15537.965415] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#15 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 8 inflight: CMD 
[15537.965419] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#15 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 14 bf e4 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[15537.965425] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#14 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 7 inflight: CMD 
[15537.965429] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#14 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 14 bf e0 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[15537.965435] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#13 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 6 inflight: CMD 
[15537.965439] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#13 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 14 bf dc 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[15537.965445] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#12 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 5 inflight: CMD 
[15537.965449] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#12 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 14 bf d8 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[18061.158174] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#26 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD 
[18061.158180] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#26 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 01 5d 45 f9 e0 00 00 00 38 00 00
[19763.079333] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#14 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 11 inflight: CMD 
[19763.079343] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#14 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 1d c8 e8 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[19763.079353] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#13 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 10 inflight: CMD 
[19763.079358] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#13 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 1d c8 e4 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[20787.100565] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#11 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 22 inflight: CMD 
[20787.100574] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#11 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 1f 05 06 18 00 00 01 e8 00 00
[20787.100584] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#10 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 21 inflight: CMD 
[20787.100588] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#10 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 1f 05 02 18 00 00 04 00 00 00
[20787.100595] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#9 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 20 inflight: CMD 
[20787.100599] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#9 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 1f 05 00 58 00 00 01 c0 00 00
[20787.100605] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#8 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 19 inflight: CMD 
[20787.100608] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#8 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 1f 04 fc 58 00 00 04 00 00 00
[20787.100615] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#7 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 17 inflight: CMD 
[20787.100618] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#7 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 1f 04 f4 58 00 00 04 00 00 00
[20787.100624] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#6 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 16 inflight: CMD 
[20787.100628] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#6 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 1f 04 f0 58 00 00 04 00 00 00
[20787.100634] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#5 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 15 inflight: CMD 
[20787.100638] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#5 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 1f 04 f0 00 00 00 00 58 00 00
[20787.100644] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#4 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 18 inflight: CMD 
[20787.100647] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#4 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 1f 04 f8 58 00 00 04 00 00 00
[20787.100653] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#3 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 6 inflight: CMD 
[20787.100657] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#3 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 1f 04 ec 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[20787.100663] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#2 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 5 inflight: CMD 
[20787.100666] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#2 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 1f 04 e8 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[21126.031966] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[21126.283450] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[56097.201861] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Spinning up disk...
[56109.504728] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] 11721045168 512-byte logical blocks: (6.00 TB/5.46 TiB)
[56109.504734] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] 4096-byte physical blocks
[56109.505022] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
[56109.505028] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[56109.505615] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[56109.506013] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
[56109.600070]  sde: sde1
[56109.629829] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
[56110.574464] EXT4-fs (sde1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[58514.106491] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#12 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[58514.106501] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#12 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 51 28 00 00 00 58 00 00
[60097.243934] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#27 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 22 inflight: CMD 
[60097.243941] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#27 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 27 ed 4c 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[60097.243948] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#26 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 15 inflight: CMD 
[60097.243951] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#26 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 27 ed 48 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[60097.243955] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#25 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 13 inflight: CMD 
[60097.243957] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#25 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 27 ed 47 f8 00 00 00 08 00 00
[60097.243962] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#24 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 12 inflight: CMD 
[60097.243965] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#24 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 27 ed 43 f8 00 00 04 00 00 00
[60097.243968] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#23 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 11 inflight: CMD 
[60097.243971] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#23 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 27 ed 43 e8 00 00 00 10 00 00
[60097.243975] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#22 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 10 inflight: CMD 
[60097.243977] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#22 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 27 ed 3f e8 00 00 04 00 00 00
[60097.243981] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#21 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 9 inflight: CMD 
[60097.243983] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#21 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 27 ed 3b e8 00 00 04 00 00 00
[60097.243986] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#20 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 8 inflight: CMD 
[60097.243989] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#20 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 27 ed 38 00 00 00 03 e8 00 00
[60097.243992] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#19 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 21 inflight: CMD 
[60097.243995] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#19 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 27 ed 24 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[60097.243999] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#18 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 20 inflight: CMD 
[60097.244001] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#18 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 27 ed 20 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[60097.244005] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#17 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 19 inflight: CMD 
[60097.244007] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#17 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 27 ed 1c 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[60097.244010] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#11 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 6 inflight: CMD 
[60097.244013] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#11 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 27 ed 34 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[60097.244016] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#10 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 5 inflight: CMD 
[60097.244019] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#10 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 27 ed 30 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[60097.244023] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#9 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 4 inflight: CMD 
[60097.244025] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#9 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 27 ed 2c 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[60097.244029] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#8 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD 
[60097.244031] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#8 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 27 ed 28 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[60097.244034] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#5 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 3 inflight: CMD 
[60097.244037] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#5 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 02 7f 00 45 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[60097.244041] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#4 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[60097.244043] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#4 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 02 7f 00 41 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[61830.849360] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#6 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[61830.849370] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#6 CDB: ATA command pass through(12)/Blank a1 08 2e d1 01 00 4f c2 00 b0 00 00
[61854.465856] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#27 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 3 inflight: CMD 
[61854.465865] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#27 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 02 ad 80 2d 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[61854.465876] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#26 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD 
[61854.465881] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#26 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 02 ad 80 29 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[62152.836014] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[62153.088605] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[62189.326090] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Spinning up disk...
[62203.648896] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] 11721045168 512-byte logical blocks: (6.00 TB/5.46 TiB)
[62203.648901] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] 4096-byte physical blocks
[62203.649175] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
[62203.649179] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[62203.649662] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[62203.650133] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
[62235.778110]  sde: sde1
[62235.807701] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
[62268.171114] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#29 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 30 inflight: CMD 
[62268.171124] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#29 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 88 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62268.171135] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#28 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 29 inflight: CMD 
[62268.171139] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#28 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 80 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62268.171145] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#27 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 27 inflight: CMD 
[62268.171149] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#27 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 78 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62268.171156] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#26 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 26 inflight: CMD 
[62268.171160] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#26 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 70 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62268.171166] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#25 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 25 inflight: CMD 
[62268.171171] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#25 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 68 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62268.171176] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#24 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 24 inflight: CMD 
[62268.171180] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#24 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 60 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62268.171186] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#23 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 23 inflight: CMD 
[62268.171190] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#23 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 58 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62268.171196] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#22 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 22 inflight: CMD 
[62268.171200] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#22 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 50 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62268.171206] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#21 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 21 inflight: CMD 
[62268.171210] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#21 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 48 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62268.171216] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#20 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 20 inflight: CMD 
[62268.171220] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#20 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 40 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62268.171227] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#19 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 19 inflight: CMD 
[62268.171230] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#19 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 38 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62268.171236] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#18 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 18 inflight: CMD 
[62268.171240] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#18 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 30 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62268.171246] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#9 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 28 inflight: CMD 
[62268.171250] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#9 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 90 00 00 00 18 00 00
[62268.171256] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#3 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 17 inflight: CMD 
[62268.171260] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#3 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 28 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62298.896340] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#15 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 4 inflight: CMD 
[62298.896349] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#15 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 38 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62298.896355] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#16 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 5 inflight: CMD 
[62298.896359] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#16 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 40 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62298.896365] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#17 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 6 inflight: CMD 
[62298.896369] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#17 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 48 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62298.896374] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#18 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 7 inflight: CMD 
[62298.896378] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#18 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 50 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62298.896383] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#19 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 8 inflight: CMD 
[62298.896387] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#19 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 58 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62298.896392] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#20 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 9 inflight: CMD 
[62298.896395] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#20 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 60 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62298.896400] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#21 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 10 inflight: CMD 
[62298.896404] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#21 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 68 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62298.896409] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#22 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 11 inflight: CMD 
[62298.896412] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#22 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 70 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62298.896417] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#23 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 12 inflight: CMD 
[62298.896421] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#23 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 78 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62298.896426] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#24 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 13 inflight: CMD 
[62298.896430] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#24 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 80 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62298.896435] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#25 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 14 inflight: CMD 
[62298.896439] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#25 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0d 88 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62329.612453] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#29 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 26 inflight: CMD 
[62329.612462] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#29 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0f e8 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62329.612473] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#28 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 25 inflight: CMD 
[62329.612478] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#28 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0f e0 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62329.612484] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#27 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 24 inflight: CMD 
[62329.612488] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#27 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0f d8 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62329.612494] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#26 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 23 inflight: CMD 
[62329.612497] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#26 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0f d0 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62329.612503] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#25 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 22 inflight: CMD 
[62329.612507] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#25 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0f c8 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62329.612513] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#24 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 21 inflight: CMD 
[62329.612517] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#24 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0f c0 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62329.612523] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#23 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 20 inflight: CMD 
[62329.612527] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#23 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0f b8 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62329.612532] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#22 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 19 inflight: CMD 
[62329.612536] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#22 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0f b0 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62329.612542] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#21 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 18 inflight: CMD 
[62329.612545] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#21 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0f a8 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62329.612551] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#20 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 17 inflight: CMD 
[62329.612555] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#20 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0f a0 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62329.612561] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#19 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 16 inflight: CMD 
[62329.612564] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#19 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0f 98 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62329.612570] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#5 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[62329.612574] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#5 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 10 10 00 00 00 10 00 00
[62329.612580] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#3 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 30 inflight: CMD 
[62329.612584] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#3 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 10 08 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62329.612590] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#2 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 29 inflight: CMD 
[62329.612593] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#2 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 10 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62329.612599] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#1 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 28 inflight: CMD 
[62329.612603] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#1 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0f f8 00 00 00 08 00 00
[62329.612608] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#0 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 27 inflight: CMD 
[62329.612612] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5d 44 0f f0 00 00 00 08 00 00
steve@steve-H97-D3H:~/java$
```

Comment: So, is the drive currently formatted as ext4 also?

Comment: @sinabala Yes, it is.  See also Addendum-2 that I have just added to the end of my question.

Comment: any lines containing `sde` from `dmesg` ? e.g. what is result from  `dmesg | grep sde` ?

Comment: @Archemar See the Addenum-3 that I have just added to the end of my question.

Comment: From what you have here, that drive is no more. Nothing is going to come from trying to salvage the data or continuing to use the disk. Unless you have backups, then the data is gone and any attempts to recover it and/or use the drive is just going to add more wear to it. Even if some of the data were still present and usable and there were just bad sectors, the most that any utility can do is to tell the operating system can do is to not write to them. It wouldn't repair them or prevent more of that from occurring. That would be the case regardless of the operating system.

Comment: @NasirRiley The way that I interpret your comment, the data is gone **and** the drive has been fatally physically damaged.  Just to clarify: should I completely scrap the hard drive, or should I attempt to "start over" by re-formatting (or whatever) the drive, so that I can start (from scratch) putting data onto it?  Is there a procedure that I can follow to "start over" with the drive?  If so, is it risky to put data on the drive, because the drive might "totally die" soon?  Has the drive been physically damaged?

Comment: @user2661923 You stated that there was a power outage while the drive was in use. According to the rest of the details in your question, you then began to receiving I/O errors among other things. As I said before, you can't start over. Once a drive has been physically damaged there is no way to undo it and continuing to use will just add wear to it. It doesn't matter anyway because the data that you had isn't even there anymore. That is all you need to know in order to make an informed decision. Hopefully, you have backups and if not, this is why they are important.

Comment: @NasirRiley Thanks very much.